# Java panacheQuery test throws nullpointer exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have a function that uses panacheQuery. This also works as intended when I test it manually. But when I write a test and execute it, I get a null pointer exception.

The test looks like this:

```
  void testFindByNameAndTag() throws ApplicationException {
    final ImageRepository repo = mock(ImageRepository.class);
    final PanacheQuery<ImageBE> panacheQuery = mock(PanacheQuery.class);

    when(repo.findByNameAndTag(anyString(), anyString())).thenCallRealMethod();
    when(repo.find(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(panacheQuery);
    when(panacheQuery.firstResultOptional()).thenReturn(Optional.of(new ImageBE()));

    final ImageBE result = repo.findByNameAndTag("name", "tag");
    assertNotNull(result);
  }
```

The findByNameAndTag function in the ImageRepository looks like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ImageRepository implements PanacheRepositoryBase<ImageBE, Long> {

  private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ImageRepository.class);

  public ImageBE findByNameAndTag(String name, String tag) throws ApplicationException {
    return find("name = ?1 and tag = ?2", name, tag)
            .firstResultOptional()
            .orElseThrow(
                    () ->
                            new ApplicationException(SOME_ERROR_CODE, SOME_ERROR_MESSAGE));
  }

}
```

Output of the test:

[image]

The exception seems to be throwed at .firstResultOptional.
Did I do something wrong with the mock or the when uses in the test?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please add further information about ImageRepository.class?

Comment: @StackInTheFloor ive provided the class with the function

Comment: Probably you need to test your method against some real data in your database to be sure that `findByNameAndTag()` is working as intended

Comment: Did you read the section about mocking in the Quarkus guides ?
See here: https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#mock-support

Comment: Anyways, maybe off-topic, but I'm not a fan of mocking repositories, while Quarkus loads automatically a db via Testcontainers in your unit test. So why not test it directly against a real db without mocking ?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add a `@QuarkusTest` annotation above your test class

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).